# Convert Videos with FFMPEG to PowerPoint 2016 compatible video format

Tags: video, ffmpeg, powerpoint, mp4, h.264

I am trying to convert a bunch of videos to a video format that is natively supported by PowerPoint 2013/2016 on a Windows 7 system.

Microsoft recommends on their website mp4 with h264 and aac.

[Video and audio file formats supported in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-PowerPoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59)

> In PowerPoint 2013 and later, and in PowerPoint 2016 for Mac, for the best video playback experience, we recommend that you use .mp4 files encoded with H.264 video (a.k.a. MPEG-4 AVC) and AAC audio. In PowerPoint 2010, we recommend that you use .wmv files.

> We recommend using .m4a files encoded with AAC audio. In PowerPoint 2010, we recommend that you use .wav or .wma files.

Audio is not important for me.
I tried to convert my videos with ffmpeg using the following options:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy Output.mp4
```

However I cannot import the video to PowerPoint 2016 (32 or 64bit, I tried both). I always get a missing codec error.

[PPT Error when including video files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d07HY.png)

Has anyone successfully encoded videos to a natively supported PowerPoint video format (on Windows)?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. SO is a Q&A page related to computer programming. Since your question does not relate to a programming problem, it is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Would migrating it to https://video.stackexchange.com/ make sense?

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution that works for me:

I forced ffmpeg to use the 'high' profile of h264 and the aac audio codec. Because the high profile doesn't support any chroma planes, I selected as pixel format YUV 4:2:0

```
ffmpeg -i Input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow  -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 22 -codec:a aac Output.mp4
```

Now it works in PP 2016 64bit on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I Corrected my mistake. A good overview about the different profiles can be found here: http://blog.mediacoderhq.com/h264-profiles-and-levels/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach was not working for me at first either. I then researched further what could be the cause. In the end, it was because my video had an audio track, but no data was available there. So a broken audio track, so to speak. Next, I deleted this audio track `ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -vcodec copy -an muted-myfile.mp4`. After that, the solution shown here worked perfectly. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: 4:4:4 apparently makes PowerPoint freeze (without any error message), thanks for making me notice that!